# Extract individual columns from an array in IDL

Tags: arrays, idl, large-data

I'm working with SDSS spectra, I read a fits file using `mrdfits`, it says the data is stored in `8 columns and 3838 rows` which is the correct dimension of the data.

But when I seek out a specific column using `print spec[0,1]` it returns an error of `out of bound`. If I use `print spec[0*1]` it gives an output of

`{11.7020      3.58080      0.0990829    0       0      1.49589      15.6233      10.8985}`

Which I think is one element and not 8. How can i separate these columns into individual ones from this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with your exact data format, but it seems like each row is a structure with 8 fields. The `HELP` command will be useful to you here:

```
IDL> help, spec[0]
```

should give you some output on how to access the columns of data. For example, I can make an example `spec` to show you (don't worry about this command, you already have a `spec`!):

```
IDL> spec = replicate({a: 0, b:0, c:0, d:0, e:0, f:0, g:0, h:0}, 3838)
```

`HELP` will tell you that you have an array of structures:

```
IDL> help, spec
SPEC            STRUCT    = -> <Anonymous> Array[3838]
```

`HELP` on an individual row will tell you the names of the fields (columns):

```
IDL> help, spec[0]
** Structure <170b6a8>, 8 tags, length=16, data length=16, refs=2:
   A               INT              0
   B               INT              0
   C               INT              0
   D               INT              0
   E               INT              0
   F               INT              0
   G               INT              0
   H               INT              0
```

You can also access an entire column:

```
IDL> help, spec.a
<Expression>    INT       = Array[3838]
```

You can slice and dice your data in a variety of ways, check out `spec[100]`, `spec[100].a`, `spec.a`, or `spec.a[100]`. You can also use normal array indexing, such as `spec[10:19].a`.